# How can I make Sublime text 3 work properly?

Tags: sublime-text

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to set Sublime 3 up, but it won't work properly, this meaning that the code doesn't display the color distinctions, so it's all white useless code. The title bar is giving me the message Sublime text(Unregistered).

Am I suppossed to download the license for it, or how do I go about setting it up properly?

Answer (score 0):

Unregistered versions of Sublime Text are not feature limited. When you open a file-type that's supported out of the box, the syntax highlighter will activate automatically. Otherwise, you can search for syntaxes (and other plugins) on the [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) website and install it (see [documentation](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/usage)). Lastly, you can assign any syntax to an open file by clicking the right-most dialog in the status bar at the bottom of the window (if no syntax was recognized, it should be labelled "Plain Text").